# Electric baseboards draw electricity, but produce no heat

Tags: heating

I recently purchased a house that has been vacant for about 6 months.  I have 4 electric baseboards. When I turn on the circuit breakers for the baseboards, they draw a lot of power (roughly 6kw from checking the meter) but produce no heat.  They don't even get slightly warm to the touch.

How would I go about diagnosing this?

Comment: 6kw is a huge amount of heat to "go missing". Are you sure you are interpreting the meter correctly? Are you sure you are checking the relevant baseboards?

Comment: @HenryJackson I'm fairly certain, and my power bill agrees.

Comment: Well something here doesn't add up, so I would start from the top and re-evaluate all of your conclusions. FYI the power bill is not really granular enough to draw any conclusions from. Are you sure you have isolated which breaker(s) control the heaters? (The panel labels may not be correct.) Are you sure there is no other controls/thermostats that may be interfering with your testing? Are you sure you are doing the meter calculations correctly? (If you have an analog meter, reading them can be tricky.) Is there another source of heat in the house that may be responsible for the power usage?

Comment: The bill I'm looking at covered a period of 2 weeks where the house was vacant.  The only thing that was on was the sump pump, the heaters, and one light.  I'm certain I have the right circuit breakers because when I have them off, I'm using less than 1kw.  When I turn them on, the usage spikes up above 6kw.  The meter is digital.  I have no appliances other than a fridge (which was purchased *after* I moved in).  The water heater is off, there's nothing else that could be drawing that kind of electricity.

Comment: If you're comfortable poking around inside your panel, you could use a clamp meter to isolate which wires (and thus circuits) are drawing a ton of juice. If you have modest electrical experience, poking around inside a panel is dangerous. Very dangerous. Please don't take this warning lightly.

Comment: You are correct.   At this point I would be searching the house for hidden extension cords leading to a nearby pot grow house!  Seriously though, it's time to start popping covers off boxes and following wires.  Be careful.   Make sure you have found -all- the heaters.  Any chance your place has floor heating and the baseboards have been bypassed and not removed?

Comment: Is the house cold?

Answer (score 1):

If 6 kW of electricity's being drawn, then a little over 20,000 BTUs of heat are being produced *somewhere* (6000 watts * 3.41 BTUs per watt). If they're not being produced at your baseboard heater, then they're being produced somewhere else between the breaker and the heater. You could have a mis-wired system that is dumping heat into a wall or something, causing a fire hazard. I would turn off the heat and call a licensed electrician if I were you.

Comment: A "system that is dumping heat into a wall or something" like as if your T-stat in the room is broken and you're heating your entire house with the one hidden in the attic or a crawlspace. IMO, the house would already be on fire or you would smell melting plastic. Did anyone stop to ask the OP if it's actually cold *in the house* or not?...

Comment: Agreed. 6kw's doesn't produce much heat. 20,000 BTUs wont heat an average home in cold weather. If the heaters are not getting hot it could be they were wired wrong, 120 volt instead of 240 for instance. They would still use power, not set fire to the house, all while not working well enough to heat the house.

Answer (score 0):

You're not cooking with gas, and a watched pot never boils.  Baseboards take a good while* to have noticeable heat.  I've been bench-testing a variety of electric heaters lately, and they're all like that.

Since you are able to use the meter as a watt-meter, add up the nameplate wattages of all the heaters.  If that accurately accounts for the wattage draw you're seeing, then it's most likely that the heaters are doing their thing.

That is to say, it's vanishingly unlikely BOTH that the heaters are broken AND some destructive malfunction is consuming exactly that amount of power.  So the only explanation is that the heaters ARE doing their thing.

Once they're fully underway, if the heat does not go where you want, that's a ducting problem.  Many electric heaters use convection, which won't work well if they're blocked in.

*as in, "a whole pop music song".

Comment: They ran for 2 full weeks, the electric bill was $200, and the heaters were still completely cold to the touch.

Comment: Of course you know, heaters cycle on and off, based on thermostat setting.

Comment: The heaters I installed a few weeks ago register on an infrared thermometer just a few seconds after turning on, and feel warm to the touch within 30 seconds.

Comment: Maybe an honest 30 seconds on a stopwatch, but people's colloquial understanding of time varies wildly, and they often go by "feels like", that's why I am conservative in my advice.  She has a **hard** problem where clues are sparse, and moving fast through the tests is a good way to miss something.

Comment: @Mark - What kind of heaters did you install? Are they an independent system?

Comment: They were industrial grade air heaters made for transit use.